# How to manage quotes when tokenizing the sentences in nltk.sent_tokenize?

Tags: nltk, tokenize

I'm trying to split the text into sentences using nltk.sent_tokenize. And I get this result when there is a quotation with more than one sentence in it:

```
t = '«I go there. Yes I go there», said John. Then he went there.'
tokenize.sent_tokenize(t)

-> ['«I go there.', 'Yes I go there», said John.', 'Then he went there.']
```

For my needs there should be two sentence here like this:

```
-> ['«I go there. Yes I go there», said John.', 'Then he went there.']
```

I understand that the result in such cases can vary and that is not an error. But how can I make nltk not to split sentences inside quotes? Or maybe there is some other tokenizers that don't do it?